# What is the best way of handling a temporary LOB in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, blob, clob

When it comes to temporary LOBs in PL/SQL, i.e. ones that won't be stored in the database, what's the best/proper way to create and dispose of them? I'm especially thinking of `dbms_lob.createtemporary` and `dbms_lob.free temporary`.

For example, how are these cases different?

```
-- CASE 1
DECLARE
    mylob CLOB;
BEGIN
    mylob = 'foo';
END;

--CASE 2
DECLARE
    mylob CLOB;
BEGIN
    dbms_lob.createtemporary( mylob, TRUE );
    mylob = 'foo';
    dbms_lob.freetemporary( mylob );
END;
```

Say I have a function that returns a LOB. Should I create a temporary lob in the function and make it the caller's responsibility to free it?

```
DECLARE
    myclob2 CLOB;

    FUNCTION myfn RETURN CLOB IS
        myclob1 CLOB := '';
    BEGIN
        dbms_lob.createtemporary( myclob1, TRUE );
        myclob1 := 'foo';
        RETURN myclob1;
    END myfn;
BEGIN
    myclob2 := myfn;
    dbms_output.put_line( myclob2 );
    dbms_lob.freetemporary( myclob2 );
END;
```

Edit:
I guess one of the things I'm especially interested in is how to properly dispose of the LOB so that it doesn't hang around until the session ends.

Comment: I'm partial to using procedures with "in out" parameters.  Easier to maintain imo.  If I have time I'll post an example later

Answer (score 0):

This is more advice than an answer. I think this is a bad question and is subjective.

That being said I typically do not recommend separating the create and free as it can lead to long term maintenance issues and abuse in the code. The same way I don't recommend opening and closing a stream or connection in separate places. Over time with multiple developers potentially involved this pattern can be error prone. Of course there are always exceptions. If you are designing an API you must consider how you will enforce that your users cleanup properly.

Also, always consider exception handling when closing resources as well. An exception thrown mid-code can prevent closing routines from executing.

Be careful with IN OUT parameters as tbone suggests without fully understanding the performance implications of using them (ie. NOCOPY hint).